# Spring mvc and webflux in 1 spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I got below instruction from spring boot doc:

> Adding both spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-webflux modules in your application results in Spring Boot auto-configuring Spring MVC, not WebFlux. This behavior has been chosen because many Spring developers add spring-boot-starter-webflux to their Spring MVC application to use the reactive WebClient. You can still enforce your choice by setting the chosen application type to SpringApplication.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE)

My question is:

**What if my application contains both MVC services and webflux services?
Is it supported?**

For example:

I may have some existing admin service which is MVC based. Now I want to add some new services with webflux style.

Answer (score 9):

No, this is not supported. Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux have different runtime models and don't support the same servers (for example, Spring WebFlux can be run with Netty, Spring MVC cannot).

Also, Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux are full web frameworks, meaning each has its own infrastructure that somehow duplicates the other. Deploying both in the same app would make it difficult to map requests (which requests should go where?).

Comment: Does that mean if I exclude netty starter and go with tomcat starter, my legacy servlet based admin will not work as well? I used to dynamic register some legacy servlet with org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializer. I guess it's will not be triggered if I go with WebApplicationType.REACTIVE. Is there any way to bypass this and make my old servlet work along with the newly added webflux service?Or I have to rewrite those servlet to webflux style?

Comment: if you have both webflux and MVC starters, MVC will be chosen by Spring Boot. If you also have the Tomcat starter, then your MVC application should work as expected; but your WebFlux endpoints won't be taken into account.

Comment: Oh, your response is so quick! Thanks a lot! Could you revisit my edit comment and give some suggestion? The situation is I have some legacy admin console is written with pure servlet + xsl, from your response, it seems I can not use it along with webflux service, right?

Comment: Technically, there might be a way to mix Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux in the same container, but you'd lose all runtime advantages with both. If you want to leverage the WebFlux non-blocking async I/O runtime, you'd need to rewrite your servlet/filters to use Servlet 3.1 non-blocking I/O, which is very hard. So in short, don't mix MVC and WebFlux.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot! The pain point is some of the internal users might choose MVC and some of them might choose WebFlux. My current admin starter is MVC/Servlet based, and I want to reused it for 2 styles. According to your answer, it seems impossible. Is there a way to to achieve this without having 2 separated starter/codebase?

Comment: @anuni Did you figure it out? I also want to have some /enpoints as reactive also I want a single code base. What approach did you follow?